# Webhooks on Parse Server

Tags: java, parse-platform, triggers, webhooks

I'm fairly new to Parse and Webhooks. I was recently assigned to study on Parse Servers and require the use of Webhook when an update to the database occur.

A high level overview is such: 
edit -> webhook trigger -> update database

Now, I've read on [this](http://docs.parseplatform.org/cloudcode/guide/#beforedelete-triggers).

Using the beforeSave trigger, and I'm confused... 
How am I suppose to trigger the beforeSave/beforeDelete, etc triggers in java?

is it similar to how we call a Cloud Code function where:

in Cloud Code:

`Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("nameOfFunction", function(request, response) {
    response.success();
});`

To call the function in java:

```
ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("nameOfFunction", params, new FunctionCallback<Float>() {
   void done(Float ratings, ParseException e) {
       if (e == null) {
          // ratings is 4.5
       }
   }
});
```

to make a trigger?

Please enlighten me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

beforeSave and afterSave triggers are automatically called if they exist.

I actually literally just wrote [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44827828/4544328) answer which has a lot of pertinent info.

These triggers go in cloud code only. There isn't a client side variant.